# How to change Pycharm ssh interpreter start location default

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm, remote-access, remote-debugging

Following [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-ssh-terminal.html), I set up a working ssh interpreter.

Starting it, always starts at `/home/myuser`

but I want a different remote directory.

Can it be done in Pycharm Pro?

Answer (score 1):

Generally for SSH, there are two ways you can do it, based on whether you want the directory change to happen for anyone who logs in as `myuser` or just you. Only the first method is compatible with PyCharm.

If you want it to apply for all users, you can configure this in the `.bashrc` on the remote system, as described here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140602/how-do-i-start-all-shell-sessions-in-a-directory-other-than-home

Nothing special will need to be done locally or within PyCharm for this option.

If you only want it to apply when you log in to the remote system, specifically from your current local system, you can provide a RemoteCommand in your local `~/.ssh/config` file (As described here: https://serverfault.com/questions/167416/how-can-i-automatically-change-directory-on-ssh-login). However, this doesn't work with PyCharm, it doesn't seem to respect the `RemoteCommand` option in `.ssh/config`

```
Host <your host alias>
     HostName <remote host IP>
     User myuser
     Port 22
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your_private_key
     RemoteCommand cd / && exec bash --login
     RequestTTY yes
```

If this did work, under `Settings > Tools > SSH Configurations` you would need to choose "OpenSSH config and authentication agent". The value you enter for `Host` will be whatever you specified as `<your host alias>` in your `.ssh/config`.

With this method, it will `cd /` if you do `ssh <your host alias>` from any terminal, but via PyCharm your session will still start in your user's home directory.

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer, but since it doesn't work with Pycharm for different users (who will want different starting locations), I will have to not accept it, maybe until technology overcomes this